# Unable to bypass gcc's -Wconversion

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main() {

    struct { unsigned int a:20; } s;
    unsigned int val = 0xaabbc000;

    s.a = val & 0xfffff;         // 1) works
    s.a = (val >> 12) & 0xfffff; // 2) generates -Wconversion warning
}
```

I'm compiling a project with `-Wconversion` and I hit a case where I'm unable to convince the compiler that I'm fine with the conversion.

- In case 1, I'm using the same solution proposed in [c++ bit fields and -Wconversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191886/c-bit-fields-and-wconversion) and it works great. It forces the compiler to accept the conversion because of the bitmask which limits value's range.
- In case 2, however, because of the shift (but why?) the compiler refuses to accept the conversion. And complains in the following way:

  ```
  $ gcc wconv.c -Wconversion -Werror
  wconv.c: In function ‘main’:
  wconv.c:8:11: error: conversion to ‘unsigned int:20’ from ‘unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
   s.a = (val >> 12) & 0xfffff; // 2) generates -Wconversion warning
         ^
  cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
  ```

  (Interesting note: with clang the code compiles without issues. I've observed so far that clang's `-Wconversion` is much less stricter than GCC's.)

**Questions:**

- How can I convince GCC to compile case 2?
- But also, why does that right shift change everything? In my understanding, given an expression having `unsigned int` type, a bit shift operation should not alter its type.
- And finally, could this be possibly a compiler bug?

**Note[1]**: this question is **not** a duplicate of: [c++ bit fields and -Wconversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191886/c-bit-fields-and-wconversion)
because the solutions proposed there simply do not work in my case.

**Note[2]**: this question is **not** a duplicate of:
[Why >>24 causes -Wconversion but >>23 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775374/why-24-causes-wconversion-but-23-doesnt) because refers to a *different* bug (or different manifestation of the same core-bug) and has a simple workaround using a cast, like proposed in [c++ bit fields and -Wconversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191886/), at least with GCC 7.3.

Comment: Interesting problem... Seems like there is some off-by-one bug in gcc's logic; Mask 0x7ffff works without warnings ;) Nor when shifting only 11 bits

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk The warning is not appropriate, since the conversion cannot really alter the value because of the mask applied before

Comment: This seems like it may be caused by [the same bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752) as [Why >>24 causes -Wconversion but >>23 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34775374/364696). That would track with @Ctx's observation about the warning not occurring when the mask or shift is tweaked by a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why >>24 causes -Wconversion but >>23 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775374/why-24-causes-wconversion-but-23-doesnt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered that in the GCC's bug tracker there are several bugs related with `-Wconversion`. In particular: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39170

Specifically, comment `#18` (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39170#c18) reports an example almost identical to mine:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo
{
   unsigned bar: 30;
   unsigned fill: 2;
};

struct foo test(uint32_t value)
{
   struct foo foo;

   foo.bar = (value >> 2) & 0x3fffffffU;

   return foo;
}
```

Therefore, I believe that this issue is definitively a **gcc bug**.

### Personal workaround

Given the compiler's bug, my personal workaround was to just wrap the right shift operation in a `static` `always_inline` function, even if I'm not particularly happy by this hack.

```
#include <stdint.h>

static __attribute__((always_inline)) inline uintptr_t
rshift(uintptr_t val, uintptr_t bits)
{
   return val >> bits;
}

int main() {

    struct { unsigned int a:20; } s;
    unsigned int val = 0xaabbc000;

    s.a = val & 0xfffff;                // 1) works
    s.a = (rshift(val, 12)) & 0xfffff;  // 2) works
}
```

### Workaround suggested by PSkocik

```
   s.a = (unsigned){(val >> 12)} & 0xfffff; // works
```

Which is my favorite by now.

Answer (score 3):

A ... workaround: use a temp variable. Not ideal, but it gets rid of the warning

```c
const unsigned t = val >> 12u;
s.a = t & 0xfffffu;
```

Other than that you could explicitly turn of the warning for the line:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
    s.a = (val  >> 12u) & 0xfffffu;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: A compound literal works too `s.a = (unsigned){(val >> 12)} & 0xfffff;`.

Comment: @bolov Your work-around proposals certainly work, but I was looking for something that has a minimal impact on the code. Using a temporary variable could be very ugly/invasive in some cases. The `#pragma` is even worse. But thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: @PSkocik I mentioned your brilliant workaround in my answer (I hope that's OK). If you post your own answer with this workaround, of course, I'll remove it from my answer and vote up yours.

Comment: @vvaltchev Nothing brilliant about it. It's just knowing that compound literals are essentially anonymous variables. :)